# Zoom level with gdaladdo

Tags: gdal, gdaladdo

I am trying to convert a .las file into mbtiles.
Here are the steps I followed:

1. Convert .las file into .tif in cloud compare.
2. Reproject the .tif file with gdalwarp.
3. Creating the tif file into different zoom level with gdaladdo command: `gdaladdo -r average cloud.tif 2 4 8 16`
4. Convert the .tif file into mbtiles with gdal_translate: `gdal_translate -outsize 512 512 cloud.tif cloud1.mbtiles -co NAME=ortho -co QUALITY=100 -co ZOOM_LEVEL_STRATEGY=AUTO -co TILE_FORMAT=PNG -co WRITE_BOUNDS=YES -of MBTILES`
5. The zoom_level for the resultant .mbtiles is fixed and I got only one zoom_level `23`

I want different zoom levels, for example, `12-24`
I tried to make different zoom level for the .mbtiles file as well with the command `gdaladdo -r average cloud1.mbtiles 2 4 8 16`, but getting the error message:

```
ERROR 6: zoom_level > 22 not supported
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hardcoded limit of z22 in the GDAL MBTiles driver that affects some operations. See this bug report https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/3126

The GeoPackage raster driver supports now zoom levels up to 29 or 30. See commit https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/d6dd4dc9b147af8871b97c63cc3dcda16a398987. This option is only available in the development version (3.9) at the moment. If you can use GeoPackage instead of MBTiles this could be on option.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to make the zoom level 22 or lower, can I do it in gdal_translate?

Comment: At the moment I fear not. The MBTiles driver does have a maxzoom option, but it is only for vector tiles https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html. But if you are very lucky then using ZOOM_LEVEL_STRATEGY=LOWER may turn the automatically selected 23 into 22.